# Turn ON raspberry pi with HI signal

Tags: boot, rpi.gpio, raspi-config

I wish to start/shutdown my raspberry with my car ignition:

1. When signal low - PI is off
2. When signal hi - PI is on

The first problem is described in many threads like [this one](https://howchoo.com/g/mwnlytk3zmm/how-to-add-a-power-button-to-your-raspberry-pi) and is straight forward to implement: I would pulldown GPIO3 and monitor (using script) the pin when it goes hi-low during turning off the ignition.

On the other hand, I need the raspberry py to turn on when ignition goes HI, whereas from what I have learned so far, Raspberry PI starts when GPIO3 is low. Is there a way to reconfigure this, so the HI signal must be provided to GPIO3 pin to start the PI?

Comment: The Pi doesn't have an "On" switch.  It automatically boots when power is applied.  So, you can use a transistor or relay wired between the USB power supply and the Pi.

Comment: @RubberStamp just added a link to my question, where it says `Simply put, shorting pins 5 and 6 (GPIO3 and GND) together will wake the Pi up from a halt state`. The power will always be provided. I just need to control ON/OFF by ignition signal.

Comment: `I wish to start/shutdown my raspberry with my car ignition` .... are you really, really sure that is what you actually want? .... think about when you want the RPi to start

Comment: The GPIO can't be configured in the off state. So I'd say 'no'.  I'd suggest to use a transistor controlled relay to momentarily connect the gpio pins when the source (ign) voltage switches on or off.  (the pi power supply will have to come from a permanent feed).

Comment: Hook into the car radio’s power line, and feed a LM350 (max 3A) with these ~12V, and output ~6.5V. Feed these 6.5V into a decent quality buck converter (~15W), and output 5V directly to 5V pin. Decouple with 1uF per ampere. On the first input use a 200V decoupling cap, and the second input a 25V cap. The LM350 will surge a bit when powered up, hence the buck converter. Forget about interfacing directly with your ignition, and just add a hall sensor to detect when the key is in a specific position. Drill a little hole in your dongle to fit a neod. magnet. Use a FET to connect pins 5->6.

Comment: You've neglected to tell us how the RPi will be powered. Will it be powered from the car's electrical system, or will it be powered from its own power source?

Comment: @Seamus The power source may not be as important. This is rather logical control issue. RPi can not just be controlled ON/OFF by HI/LOW signal. If I understand correctly, turning ON/OFF both require pulsing the pin LOW for a short time, so simple level voltage control may not work.

Comment: @Nazar: It's important in terms of how to design an interface. But you don't need to answer.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I have missed the pulldown resistor in my illustration for the accessories to ground. Don't forget that or you will get a floating value when the car is on!

I know this is old but in the off chance it helps someone, I thought I might share my solution. I'm pretty new to all of this so please, if I am doing anything stupid, let me know.

A small, external circuit can help with this. It will need two inputs: 12v constant and 12v from the accessories switch. You will also need to connect the RPI to the car ground and the circuit to the same ground.

[image: Circuit diagram]

I used a logical XOR gate rated for 3-20v such as the cd4030be. Hook it up to constant 12v on both its power pin and first input to one of its gates. Hook up the ground to the ground pin.

Put the accessories line onto the second input on the first gate. Use a resistor on this pin to ground to pull it down when accessories are off. So essentially, this is now a not gate. When accessories is on, the output is off and visa versa.

Now, make a voltage divider. To be safe, I used 100k for R1 and 20K for R2. This gives somewhere between 2 and 3 volts at the extremes. Run the output of that pin through this and run that finally to the output.

Hook up pin 3 to this and the pi will now turn on when the accessories are switched on. I went further and added a python script to monitor the pin and if it goes high for more than 10 seconds, it shuts down.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Welcome Justin! I think this answer could be enhanced if you add a circuit schematic to illustrate it :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I have added my crude drawing :)

Comment: A reasonable answer I think. But to @David 's point, if you used the [RPi SE schematic editor](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2074/how-do-i-add-a-schematic-to-my-question), you could add that pull down you need ever so easily :)

Answer (score 1):

Driving a 3.3V pin with a 12V signal will require a level shifter anyway, and inverting level shifters have essentially the same complexity as non-inverting ones.

For instance, here's an example using an optocoupler:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFlf6s.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The advantage of an optocoupler is that you don't have to have the same ground on both sides. It's usually not a problem to have common ground, but in a car different grounding points may have drastically different potential during motor startup (hundreds of amps flowing though some wires and not others). Feeding a negative voltage into a GPIO (as little as 0.5V) is enough to destroy the Pi.

Comment: I think the optocoupler is a good way to isolate grounds, but if the RPi is powered via the same source (battery/alternator), does it make any difference?

Comment: @Seamus At 300 amps different parts of a conductor are not "the same source". I doubt the OP will power their Pi directly from the ignition relay contacts.

Comment: Perhaps not, but at some point it's gotta' be grounded - unless of course you bring in the RPi with its own power source. Other "delicate" electronic systems survive in the automotive environment, and I'd have to guess that the RPi could also survive with some precautions. My point was not to take exception with your answer - I think it's a good one - but only to suggest that if the RPi draws its power from the car's electrical system the advantages of opto-isolation do not extend to cover all risks from that environment.